# Two Way Binding Not Working In Directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a Directive used as follows :

```
<planner-view ng-controller="plannerController"></planner-view>
```

The template is as follows :

```
<div ng-repeat="day in itinerary" class="day">
    <div ng-repeat="attraction in day" class "attraction">
        <div ng-include="'/public/angular/templates/attraction-card.html'"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The `plannerController` has the following :

```
app.controller('plannerController', function($scope, $element){
    $scope.itinerary = null;
    $scope.itinerary = [[...], [...], [...]];
```

Everything is being rendered properly.

Now I am trying to add a behavior where if you drag an `attraction` class element from one of the `day` class element and drop it in another one, it gets moved there. To do this, I update the `itinerary` array and let the two way binding update the HTML. But this does not happen. The array gets updated, but the HTML does not change.

The move is being handled as follows :

```
var deletedElement = $scope.itinerary[oldDayClass].splice(currentAttractionID,1);
$scope.itinerary[newDayClass].push(deletedElement);
```

The log for the array shows that the array is being updated, but the HTML does not change.
Is this not possible ? Where could I be going wrong ?

Comment: Don't write down tags in question's title: associated tags are enough ;)

Comment: Are you using an angular event to detect the drag-and-drop or a native DOM/jQuery event? If the latter, are you handling the move inside a $scope.$apply call?

Comment: Had not written inside the $scope.$apply call. Worked! :)